# shift one row down in a matrix/data frame in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to shift rows in my data frame, Not to trnaspose data but move first row to second row, second row to third row .. and drop last row. First row contain all NA. I need to do within dplyr. If the data frame was:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I want data as follows:

```
NA NA NA
1  2  3 
4  5  6
```

Basically I need similar to pandas shift (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) in r

Thanks in advance

Comment: The data.table package has a function `shift` that will do this for you with a data.frame, like `setDF(shift(DF))[]`

Comment: `rbind(NA, d[-nrow(d), ])` works for one row.

Comment: Thanks, anything in dplyr ?

Comment: This is a hack using `dplyr` but you can try the following `rbind(NA, df %>% filter(row_number()!=1))`

Comment: Idiomatically in `dplyr`: `your_data %>% mutate_each(funs = funs(lag))`.

Comment: For matrix `mat` and with **dplyr**: `t(dplyr::lag(t(mat),3))`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Comment to answer, the most idiomatically dplyr method I can think of is `lag` and `mutate_all`. Demo on `mtcars`:

```
mtcars %>% mutate_all(.funs = funs(lag))
```

Comment: mutate_each deprecated. Use `mtcars %>% mutate_all(funs(lag), n=1)`

Comment: Error in inherits(x, "fun_list") : 
  argument ".funs" is missing, with no default?

Comment: @puzzler10 replaced `funs =` with `.funs =`. Works now.